# EPPlus reading date column incorrectly when there are forward slash in the text value

Tags: epplus

Excel file  row =2, column =3  (for example).  Cell is formatted as Date `mm/dd/yyyy` and contains the value 9/13/2018.

EPPlus code:

```
Dim entrydate As String = worksheet.Cells(2, 3).Text
```

entrydate is 13.

If cell format is changed to `yyyy-mm-dd`, the read is fine.

How to delimit or escape forward slashes?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the latest EPPlus.  Prior version works fine.  This is the workaround for now:

Prior to reading the cell, changing date format to `yyyy-MM-dd`.

```
worksheet.Cells(2, 3).Style.NumberFormat.Format="yyyy-MM-dd"
Dim entrydate As String = worksheet.Cells(2, 3).Text
```